# Error trying to access Gmail on all browsers, "bad_mac_alert"

Tags: macos, gmail, google-chrome, firefox, web-browser

Recently I've been getting this error in Chrome when I try to access Gmail or other google sites.

```
Error 126 (net::ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT): Unknown error.
```

In Firefox it's

```
An error occurred during a connection to accounts.google.com.

SSL peer reports incorrect Message Authentication Code.

(Error code: ssl_error_bad_mac_alert)
```

Using OS X Lion.  It used to work, but then there was a power failure, and now this is happening.

Searches online found some results, but nothing seems to work. Tried turning on and off "Set date and time automatically".

Comment: Is it possible your Internet is going through a proxy that is modifying your traffic?  (Have you tried connecting through a different source of Internet?)

Comment: Obviously, your Mac is misbehaving. You should shake your finger at it and yell "Bad Mac! Bad! No treats for you today unless you start behaving!" and then send it to bed with no dinner.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is a [pretty common issue](http://www.google.com.ph/#sclient=psy&hl=tl&site=&source=hp&q=ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT&pbx=1&oq=ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=464l464l0l1108l1l1l0l0l0l0l262l262l2-1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=2fb39c54306197a7&biw=1422&bih=366).  Have you tried [clearing your cache and browser data](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95582)?  Also do you get the same error with different browsers?  Try Safari and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Yes I know there are plenty of hits on Google, but without any useful suggestions.  Safari was the same thing, but I just didn't bother mentioning it.
The error for Chrome and Firefox is shown in the question, and it's essentially the same error.  Thanks for the clearing cache suggestion, that is a good idea.  I'll try it out.

Comment: I have the same issue and I tried clearing my cache and browser data but it didn't work.